# Implement Flex Chart in JSP

Tags: apache-flex, jsp, integration, chartfx

I have a jsp which displays future sales chart along with other contents(button,textbox.etc) and this chart has been implemented using chartfx.
Now I have a requirement to implement this chart using Adobe flex without modifying other components in the jsp.

How do I start?What would be the correct approach?Am new to flex and hence finding it difficult to arrive at a solution.
Pls help.Thanks

Comment: I dont hav a clear idea on this.I hav written the mxml,with a xml as input,it generates a chart,but how do I do it on the fly,inside a jsp?is it feasible in the 1st case?

Comment: You can do just about anything you want with Flex and there are tons of approaches to do what you ask for. Perhaps you should describe your current architecture so that we can come up with a workflow that reuses it as much as possible. That said, I fail to see the point of creating (and have the user loading) a Flex application just to draw a chart. There are some very good JS charting libraries out there. Probably even better than the Flex charts since they are becoming quite old.